# Php variable not getting incremented in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to increment `$j` in `$.each` function of jquery. But `$j` is not getting incremented. What may be the reason. My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url : "test.php",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "categoryIds" : categoryIds
        },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(resp){
            var html = "";
            var i = 1;
            <?php $j = 1; ?>
            $.each(resp,function(key,questions ){
                <?php
                $j = 1;
                $testdataIndex  = "answer_".$j;
              ?>
              var test = "<?php  echo $testdataIndex?>";
             alert(test);
                         var res = "<?php echo $_SESSION['testdata'][$testdataIndex]; ?> ";
            var index = "<?php  echo $j++;?>";
            alert(index);
      });
});
```

Each time `test` prints 'answer_1' and `index`  as 1

Comment: Of course it won't because your PHP is executed first before your jQuery, so it will always print the same value. You should consider saving the PHP variable to JavaScript's and then increment it.

Comment: That's is not possible. you are mixing php with jquery....

Comment: PHP is server side, JS is client side. Feel da difference.

Comment: So, how should I sort it out?Any solution?

Comment: `var js_j = "<?php echo $j ?>"`;
`js_j++;`

Comment: Looking at your code again, you seem to be using counter to retrieve different value from your `SESSION` variables, you should look up on [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it allows you to mingle with PHP without page load.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger : Thanks.Will try to implement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed session issue :

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url : "test.php",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "categoryIds" : categoryIds
        },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(resp){
            var html = "";
            var i = 1;
            <?php $j = 1; ?>
            $.each(resp,function(key,questions ){
               var testdataIndex  = "answer_" + i ;
               var  filename = "getsession.php?sessionName="+testdataIndex;
               $.get(filename, function (data) 
                     {
                        sessionValues = data;
                        $("#"+testdataIndex).text(sessionValues);
               });//get
               html += '<textarea class="form-control answer"  rows = "5"  style="width:127%;" id="answer_'+i+'" name="answer_'+i+'" required="required"></textarea>';
              i++;
      });//each
});//ajax
```

**getsession.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$sessionName = $_GET['sessionName'];
print ($_SESSION['testdata'][$sessionName]);
?>
```

I have answered my question for other who face same problem.